# Load external url into a div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, stripe-payments

I am trying to load an external url using axios into a div using vuejs and I am getting

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at `<CompleteUrl>` from origin `<MyWebsiteUrl>` has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What am I missing?

**Stack Trace:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1Gje8uKs9y22NbsB/ch_1GwhguKs9y22NbsBgOgk5dk4/rcpt_HVj9h5buO4Yz2ucIeq66MNBdxGX8Ytu' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Vue Js code:**

```html
<template>  
    <div id="invoice-page" v-html="paymentReceipt">

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

let response=await axios.get('https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1Gje8uKs9y22NbsB/ch_1GwhguKs9y22NbsBgOgk5dk4/rcpt_HVj9h5buO4Yz2ucIeq66MNBdxGX8Ytu');
this.paymentReceipt= response.data;
</script>
```

**Update 1:**
I see that the https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1Gje8uKs9y22NbsB/ch_1GwhguKs9y22NbsBgOgk5dk4/rcpt_HVj9h5buO4Yz2ucIeq66MNBdxGX8Ytu url's response headers=>x-frame-options is set to sameorigin, therefore I cannot even embed the payment receipt url in an iFrame on my website.

Comment: If it is your backend, you have to enable cors in backend.

Comment: Have you looked up this error? https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: What is your backend? Node.js?

Comment: My backend is a mixture of Lambda functions written in .net, NodeJs. However in this specific scenario, my application completes a payment to stripe and is trying to show the stripe payment receipt in my application. I am assuming that I have to show the data from the Payment Recipt url ("https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1Gje8uKs9y22NbsB/ch_1GwhguKs9y22NbsBgOgk5dk4/rcpt_HVj9h5buO4Yz2ucIeq66MNBdxGX8Ytu") in an Iframe when the payment is successful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm nearly certain you can't show the receipt URL inside an IFRAME, which is why you're getting this error.  You should instead use the data from the Charge - or the Payment Intent, or whatever you're creating - to indicate the status.